# Using MAC Filtering in addition to WPA2 Encryption

Tags: router, wpa2, mac-address, wpa2-psk, mac-spoofing

I've been trying to find some answers regarding using MAC filtering on my router in addition to having WPA2 encryption but I couldn't find any clear ones. I understand that using MAC filtering solely is bad security practice since anyone can spoof any MAC address by using certain tools and use that MAC to connect to the network.
If I have WPA2 enabled and someone uses one of my whitelisted MAC addresses, will they be able to connect to my network without providing the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your network uses WPA2, then clients must connect using WPA2 and the appropriate authentication method (e.g. PSK). MAC filtering doesn't really have to do anything with WPA2, it just adds another layer of access control that determines which devices are allowed to connect.

Comment: That is what I wanted to confirm. I guess I didn't word it right, I didn't mean WPA2 has anything to do with MAC filtering but has extra layer of access control a you said. Thank you very much!